# $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n !ne+ (-1)^{(n+1)} n! = 0 \: ?$

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n  !ne+ (-1)^{(n+1)} n! = 0 \: ?$

$!n$ is the [subfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html). Here's a plot made with [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%20(-1)%5En%20*%20!n*e%2B%20(-1)%5E(n%2B1)%20n!)%20from%200%20to%2015):

[image]

Maybe the function goes to $0$ at infinity. How to prove this analytically? I wanted to have a better understanding of how this function behaves. If we changed $e$ to $2.7182$, which is close to the actual value of $e$ the graph changes to:

[image]

So it's only going to $0$ because of $e$?

Answer (score 1):

Using that

$$!n=n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!},$$

we have

$$!n=\frac{n!}{e}-n!\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

So

$$n!-e!n=en!\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=e\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n!(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Think back to the proof that $e$ is irrational. Can you use similar logic to show that this last sum tends to $0$ as $n$ grows large? Can you use this to conclude that your original limit tends to $0$?

For your second question, think about what happens when we replace $e$ with some number very close to $e$. How does this differ from this limit?